# Regex not matching string (OCaml Str module)

Tags: regex, string, ocaml

I have this preword and regex:

```
let regex = Str.regexp "\\([A-Za-z0-9]\\.*[A-Za-z0-9]\\)";;
let s = "--O--c-a-l**9+===";;
```

My regex is matching for a string that begins with a letter or number, has 0 to as many character in between, and ends with a letter or number. So the substring "`O--c-a-l**9+`" should match.

But when I see if my preword matches my regex, it keeps saying it doesn't match

```
Str.search_forward regex s 0;;
Exception: Not_found.
```

And I'm not sure what I'm missing in my regex for it to not match my string.

---

### **[Str documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html)**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You escaped the `.`, so it will only match literal dots. To match any character, remove the `\\`.